# Rhythmbox stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16

Tags: sound

So, I had my Ubuntu 15 with Rhythm working fine. Then, when it was released, I upgraded to Ubuntu 16 and after that Rhythmbox stopped working.

When I open it, or click in some audio file, it shows up but just does absolutely nothing - keep showing "Not Playing" for all kinds of audio files.

I don't think it's a Hardware problem, because I'm able to reproduce audio files through other players such as Audacious or even the terminal itself; Neither  plug-ins problem once I've installed all the gstreamers plugings with Synaptic and nothing happened as well.

If is there someone whom could know something, please, help me. Rhythmbox is the best music player I've ever known and I really wish it to work again.